# How to check version of currently loaded runtime on an Azure worker node?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to add an Azure worker node into an existing HPC grid used by my app. My assemblies are .Net 4, but when I do a SOA Service Loading test on the Azure node, it fails with:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Resources\directory\83bc35663f404fd5a523fb9eb183e663.HpcSmallWorker.Application\foo\2011-08-10T100606.0000000Z\foo.myDLL.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

In the service config file there is

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Is there any way I can check what the current runtime is on the worker? As I understand it I cannot RDP onto this as it's not a VM role.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4 is loaded on all current guest OSes (as well as .NET 2, 3.5, etc.).  Are you sure you including the .dll in your package?

You can RDP into any role type (Web, Worker, VM Role).  To enable that, try hitting publish in Visual Studio and look for configure rdp connection link.

Comment: I get the same error if I use the SquareService HPC example, and change the target runtime of the SquareService project from 3.5 to 4 - looks like my Azure workers are not happy with .Net 4 assemblies.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the assembly on the machine?  I would either crack open the package locally, or RDP into a running machine and look in the AppRoot (usually e:\approot).  If you don't find your assembly there, it is not getting packaged.

Comment: I don't understand your comment - it's not a file not found error, the error says it can't load the assembly due to the runtime version.

Comment: Just noticed that you are trying to launch something from a local resource.  As I said, all versions of .NET are present, so it is how you are launching it.  I suspect your .config file is either in the wrong location or you are launching from a different process than you think you are.  Please give more context on how you are launching and from where (e.g. how did a local resource get here)? Can you explain more what you are doing?  Why isn't this packaged in your role code?  Or is this all tied to how HPC does things?